# Настройка .htacces для работы на локальном сервере

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, hosting

Всем привет не могу разобраться с хитрым файлом .htacces для того что бы скопированный сайт заработал на локалке для дальнейшей доработки. Как я понял автор этого произведения очень в стародавние времена защитил сайт от взлома и частично завязал работу движка на данный конструкт.
Основная проблема что не могу перевести на тестовый локальный адрес а-ля `localhost:888/domain/`
До этого не сталкивался с подобной реализацией, при любом запросе на локалхост получаю редирект на боевой сайт. Каким образом его можно переписать для нормальной работы на локальном хостинге. Используется MAMP на macOS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteRule (.*) G_index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/login/$ admin/cms_login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/login$ admin/cms_login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/cms_index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/cms_index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ G_index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ G_index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/$ forum [L]
RewriteRule ^forum$ forum [L]
RewriteRule ^foto/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ G_index.php?id=foto&album=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^foto/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ G_index.php?id=foto&album=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ns/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ G_index.php?id=ns&ns=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ns/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ G_index.php?id=ns&ns=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ns/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ G_index.php?id=ns&ns_date=$1&page_num=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^hr/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ G_index.php?id=hr&wr=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^hr/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ G_index.php?id=hr&wr=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^hr/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ G_index.php?id=hr&wr=$1&page_num=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ admin/cms_index.php?id=$1&article=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ admin/cms_index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ admin/cms_index.php?id=$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /core.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: со второй по 4 строки - редирект на domain.ru. если вы об этом, можете просто их выкинутт

Comment: Да это помогло были еще определенные проблемы но ваше совет сильно ускорил поиск проблемы.